# Layerslider WP continue after video played/paused

Tags: wordpress, video, slider, layer, autostart

I embed a Youtube hosted video in LayerSlider WP 5.3.2, the slider has an option to "Pause the slide" with values "while video is playing/permanently/no action". I want to use "while video is playing", that is to continue the slider animation after the video is played/paused, but this option doesn't work.

Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance!